# $X\sim U[0,1]$, given $X=x$, $Y\sim U[0,x],$ what is $\rho(X,Y)?$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to compute $$\rho(X,Y)=\frac{\text{Cov}[X,Y]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[X]\text{Var}[Y]}}=\frac{E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[X]\text{Var}[Y]}}.$$

I know that $E[X]=1/2$, $\text{Var}[X]=1/12$. To complete this problem I need to find $E[Y]$ and $E[XY]$. For $E[Y]$ the mean should be is $(0+x)/2=x/2$ but the book says $1/4$, why?

For $E[XY]$ I have that

$$E[XY]=\int_0^1\int_0^xxy\cdot f(x,y) \ dydx,$$

but how do I find the joint distribution $f(x,y)?$ Sure if they stated that $X$ and $Y$ are independent then I could use that $f_X(x)f_Y(x)=1\cdot 1/x=1/x$ but I can't assume independence.

Comment: The joint distribution is not needed for finding $\rho(X,Y)$, as is shown in the answer below. Use the conditional distribution itself to find the answer. You would also need $V(Y)$ which can be found similarly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you found was: $$\mathbb E[Y\mid X=x]=\frac12 x$$

That means that: $$\mathbb E[Y|X]=\frac12 X$$ and applying the general rule: $$\mathbb EY=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y|X]]$$ we then find that: $$\mathbb EY=\mathbb E\frac12X=\frac12\mathbb EX=\frac12\frac12=\frac14$$

Applying that same rule in this form:$$\mathbb E[XY]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[XY\mid X]]$$and exploiting that: $$\mathbb E[XY\mid X]=X\mathbb E[Y|X]$$
we find: $$\mathbb E[XY]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[XY\mid X]]=\mathbb E[X\mathbb E[Y\mid X]]=\mathbb E\frac12X^2=\frac12\mathbb EX^2=\frac12\frac13=\frac16$$

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!